# About Artificial Intelligence

Tags: java, c++, algorithms, data-structures

I am interested in starting a career in artificial intelligence.

Can anyone suggest how I could prepare for this?

What languages should I study that would be best for this career choice?

Comment: what language you should learn next is off-topic per site **[FAQ]**

Comment: There are as many preferred languages for AI as there are domains within AI.  Machine learning is quite different than computer vision which is different than natural language processing, which is again different than game theory.  Talk to professors at your university who teach AI to get a better idea of the specifics for the problem domains you are interested in.

Comment: career-related questions are not welcome here. Moreover, your question is a duplicate of the following question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/167701/32008

Comment: If you think that you learn AI by learning a language (even if it's an AI specific language) you should probably quit now and get a career in the construction industry. For a career in AI you should learn a lot of maths and prob. theory. The language is immaterial.

Answer (score 4):

The language matters little. Study the algorithms and the logic behind the AI concepts. If you are able to understand that, implementing it is possible in any language. I myself have been using Java, but that's just a personal choice.

Also, try the book:
**Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach** 
Stuart Russel, Peter Norvig, Prentice Hall, 3rd edition, 2009

Comment: +1 as the computer will only run machine code anyway, no matter what "language" you think you are writing. :)  Some languages do fit some problems better than others, but you'll only learn where the real pain points lie with experience.

Answer (score -2):

You can code with whatever language you are comfortable in, provided it's object oriented.. Python, C++ o Java.. it's upto you.. There's good course on udacity.com in AI by Sebastian Thrun, The course is based on making robotic car using AI in all fields like computer vision, sensing, pattern recognition, learning etc.. Its a good course to get started...!

Comment: Why is object orientation needed for AI?

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts a differing opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like "whatever language you are comfortable in, provided it's _not_ object oriented", how would this answer help reader to pick of these differing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape

Comment: Of course any language can be used for AI, but I personally think that Java or python gives the user many features that are required for AI, This is my personal opinion, as I've benefited a lots from python.The udacity.com course  also uses python for programming. But even then I say, You can use the language you are comfortable in.
Also you may try out courses on  coursera.org which are also interesting....!